# how to call a function from a div tag in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a card grid layout in my HTML code, to get/load the dynamic data for the same I need to call a function say loadRoomObjects in the DIV tag as shown in the below code

```
<div class="card_grid widget uib_w_33 wrapping-col d-margins flex-basis-33" data-uib="layout/card_grid" data-ver="0">
      <div class="widget widget-container content-area vertical-col uib-card uib_w_34 section-dimension-34 cpad-0" data-uib="layout/card" data-ver="0">
        <h4 class="card-tittle">{{testing(Room)}}</h4>  
            <div class="list-group widget uib_w_38 d-margins" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/list_group" data-ver="1">
              <a class="list-group-item allow-badge widget uib_w_39" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/list_item" data-ver="1">
                <p class="list-group-item-text">bed</p>
              </a>
              <a class="list-group-item allow-badge widget uib_w_40" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/list_item" data-ver="1">
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Stove</p>
              </a>
              <a class="list-group-item allow-badge widget uib_w_41" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/list_item" data-ver="1">
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Tap</p>
              </a>
            </div>

      </div>
```

I am not sure how to achieve this using the given directives in AnjularJS, as I could not find a suitable ng-directive which call a perticular function in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try calling `loadRoomObjects` function using `ng-init` directive .

The **ngInit directive** allows you to *evaluate an expression in the current scope*.

it can be used with div like  :

```
 <div ng-init="loadRoomObjects()" ></div>
```

Check the docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem as simple as creating a Scope variable to store the room objects (i.e.. `$scope.room_objects = loadRoomObjects()`). Call `ng-repeat="roomObject in room_objects"` on your *div* in HTML code

Ctrl:

```
$scope.room_objects = loadRoomObjects();
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="room_object in room_objects" class="card_grid widget ...">
....      
</div>
```

Additionally we can keep a **watcher** on **room_objects** scope variable to keep the HTML in sync with the Ctrl code.